# convert string to enum and passing in struct

Tags: c, function, struct, enums, project

I am working on a school project. The goal is to make a function where i initialize the game. Input value of the function is a structure. Output is a structure too. BUT, i am having a problem in the last part of the output structure. 
In the last part, i have to compare the raw_map string with characters and make from it an output consist of enums. Code:

**input struct**

```
typedef struct level {
char* raw_map;      // original string representing the level map
char* name;         // level name
char* description;  // level description
char* password;     // level password
struct level *next; // pointer to the next level
} LEVEL;
```

**output struct**

```
typedef struct game {
int x;      // player x position
int y;      // player y position
int width;  // map width
int height; // map height
int steps;  // number of steps player made
MAP_ITEM **map;  // game map
} GAME;
```

**MAP_ITEM**

```
typedef enum {
EMPTY,
WALL,
BOX,
DELIVERED,
DESTINATION
} MAP_ITEM;
```

**the following raw_map string**

```
level->raw_map="-----#####-----------|-----#@$.#-----------|-----#####-----------";
```

**output **map string should look like**

```
.map = {
    {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, WALL, WALL, WALL, WALL, WALL, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY},
    {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, WALL, EMPTY, BOX, DESTINATION, WALL, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY},
    {EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, WALL, WALL, WALL, WALL, WALL, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY}
}
}
```

**My code:**

```
GAME* init_game(LEVEL* level){
GAME* init;
init=(LEVEL*)malloc(100*sizeof(LEVEL*));
int i,x=0,y=1;
char string[strlen(level->raw_map)+1];
char* rawMapa,*mapa[50][50];
strcpy(string,level->raw_map);
rawMapa=&string;
printf("%s\n",string);

//width & height
for(i=0;i<=strlen(string);i++){
    if(string[i]!='|')
        x++;
    else break;
}
init->width=x;
for(i=0;i<=strlen(string);i++)
    if(string[i]=='|')
        y++;
init->height=y;
y=0;
x=0;    

//player
i=0;
while(string[i]!='@'){
    if(string[i]!='|')
        x++;
    if(string[i]=='|'){
        y++;
        x=0;
    }
    i++;
}
init->x=x;
init->y=y;
init->steps=0;


/*!! PROBLEM HERE !!*/
//map item
init->map=(char**)malloc(100*sizeof(char**));
*init->map=&level->raw_map;
i=0;
while(level->raw_map!=EOF){
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='#'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=WALL;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='-'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=EMPTY;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='@'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=EMPTY;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='$'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=BOX;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='.'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=DESTINATION;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='+'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=DESTINATION;
    }
    if(*(level->raw_map+i)=='*'){
        *(init->map+i)=(MAP_ITEM*)malloc(10*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
        *(init->map+i)=DELIVERED;
    }
    i++;
}


return init;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
init->map = (MAP_ITEM**)malloc(init->height*sizeof(MAP_ITEM*));
for (i=0; i<init->height; i++)
{
    init->map[i] = (MAP_ITEM*)malloc(init->width*sizeof(MAP_ITEM));
    for (j=0; j<init->width; j++)
    {
        switch (level->raw_map[i*(init->width+1)+j])
        {
            case '-': init->map[i][j] = EMPTY      ; break;
            case '@': init->map[i][j] = EMPTY      ; break;
            case '#': init->map[i][j] = WALL       ; break;
            case '$': init->map[i][j] = BOX        ; break;
            case '.': init->map[i][j] = DESTINATION; break;
            case '+': init->map[i][j] = DESTINATION; break;
            case '*': init->map[i][j] = DELIVERED  ; break;
        }
    }
}
```